# Randomly generated sprites for a game?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using this method i created to randomly create different sprites to be added to my scene using andEngine.

```
 Random randItem = new Random();



     face = null;
     float x = rand.nextInt((int) mCamera.getWidth() - mBallTextureRegion.getHeight());
        int ItemNumber = randFruit.nextInt(6) + 1;

        if(ItemNumber == 1){
            face = new Sprite(x,0, this.mBallTextureRegion);


        }else if(ItemNumber == 2){


            face = new Sprite(x,0,this.strawberryTextureRegion);

        }else if(ItemNumber == 3){

            face = new Sprite(x,0,this.grapeTextureRegion);

            }else if(ItemNumber == 4){
                face = new Sprite(x,0, this.watermelonRegion);

            }else if(ItemNumber == 5){
                face = new Sprite(x,0, this.cherryRegion);


            }else if(ItemNumber == 6){
                Sprite poison = new Sprite(x,0,this.poisionRegion);







            }
```

What i am doing is randomly generating numbers 1 - 6. And testing each time to see which number is generated and then i add the correct sprite according to the numbER.

So the problem is..Since this is for a game project using AndEngine. I want to randomly generate bonus items that are randomly generated but not generated as often as the sprites above. This should only happen in like once every few 100 sprites that are added.

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Like a class created just for this purpose?

Or am i on the right track? Any help will be greatly apprecciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a `switch` statement rather than nested `if-statements` to check which item you want.

You can implement a chance to drop additional random generated items every `x` percentage if you want aswell, rather than putting a hard-counter on it (e.g. every 100), consider something like this:

```
int itemNumber = randFruit.nextInt(6) + 1;

switch(itemNumber) {
   case 1:
      //Item 1 code
      break;
   case 2: 
      //Item 2 code
      break;
   //etc. . . 
 }

//Generate random number from 1 - 100
int randomItem = (int)(Math.Random()*100);

if (randomItem >= 90 && <= 100) {
  //Generate your item
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion alot. I never thought about using a switch statement for this. So in the randomly generated 1 - 100. How would that look inside of the switch statement? As far as the Cases. And how could i have random Bonus points that arent prone to being generated back to back or one after another?

Comment: You can use a switch for the random generated 1 - 100, but keep in mind that Java doesn't support ranges in a switch statement, so you would have to put each case in there. If you are working with a small range of numbers, switch makes the code look cleaner; but for probability things such as "random" items, it'll be much easier to use if-statements.

Comment: So if i wanted to randomly add a bonus item to the scene..but randomly..I dont want it to add randomly to the point where 4 could be possibly added back to back.

Comment: That is what the "randomItem" code above is for; You limit your if-test based on the probability you want of this occurring. At the moment it is a 10% chance that a random item will occur. You can decrease the test (e.g. >= 98 && <= 100) to change the probability accordingly. It is also possible that even whilst you're using probability - it is still possbile for 4 to drop in a row, then none to drop for a long time :)

Comment: See and thats the issue. I dont want it to go a while without anything dropping. I want one of the numbers to be a case constantly..For example..if the random number 91 is selected and it doesnt have a case..nothing happens..and the same thing for the rest..This seems to the issue with the approach.